# Internal hard disk does not mount on Ubuntu: Just one unknown partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have received an old hard drive (previously used in Drobo) and want to extract its data. Not sure how was used in Drobo and what has been the filesystem type.

I connect it to my systems which has Ubuntu 18.04 installed. The disk is recognized in the "Disks" but cannot be mounted. The drive seems to have only one partition (e.g. /dev/sdc) and shown as Unknown.

[image: Image taken from Disk]

When checking the options in the gears on the bottom-left side (see attached), all the options except "Format Partition, Create Partition Image, Restore Partition Image, and Benchmark Partition" are deactivated.

I was wondering if there is a solution for how to extract the data from this hard drive?

Thanks in advance for your comments.
Cheers

Comment: Drobos normally put the drive into either a RAID 5, RAID 6, etc.  which probably means that this drive was part of an array and without the other disks you may not be able to recover or copy anything from it.

Comment: Each should be an independent copy of the files, though. Is not it? Anyway, I have other drives used in the same Drobo. Could you please explain how to use all of them to recover the data? Tnx

Comment: The RAID they setup are striped sets for redundancy if 1 or possibly 2 drives fail.  But because this data is striped without the other disks the data is incomplete.  It has been a long time since I used a Drobo last, but if the unit went bad you might have a chance if you could put them all back in another unit.  If not, I don't know if it can be done due to the encoding type that the Drobo may use.

Comment: I checked another SATA hard drive which has the same problem BUT has not been used in Drobo. So, maybe it is not merely because of Drobo.

Comment: Where did the other drive come from?  Also, some controllers in computers might have issues reading drives larger than 2TB.  Usually that is in older systems.  However, back to the Drobo thing, or any other RAID like that, and if I remember correctly that a Drobo used at least the RAID 5 possibly a RAID 6, the data might theoretically be recoverable, but the partition that was setup to store the data would be incomplete so the partition would not be able to be mounted.  Thus, the only way to more than likely recover anything from that single drive would be for an app like photorec...

Comment: that can do individual files.  But there are no guarantees.

Comment: It also looks like Drobo uses their own proprietary stuff which would make it impossible to mount any of these drives in a standard computer.  https://www.drobo.com/reality-check-all-raid-is-proprietary/

Comment: Thanks, Terrance. It is disappointing.